# Debugging python code in subprocess using Breakpoints in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I have been trying to debug a massive PyTorch model in VScode.
The starting point of the code first processes a configuration file, and then runs a `subprocess` containing the cofigs.
The issue is that after calling `subprocess.call` functions, the VScode, the code is executed in an external sub-process, which does not allow to use breakpoint.
example code:

```
def main():
    args = parse_args()
    cmd = construct_cmd(args)
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

where `cmd` is the string command to be executed, but after this line, all breakpoints are ignored (probably because a sub-process runs this command.
Any solutions how to solve this?

Comment: Can't you run `cmd` directly with a default config for debugging? 
Just excluding the script that calls the subprocess from the equation?

Comment: Not a `deep-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).